# Login function in PHP

Tags: php, security, authentication

I've been working on a simple login script. The registration part is still to be coded, but I'm done the login part. Are there any security holes in my code? I'm using SHA-512 right now but I think I'll change it to mcrypt later.

```
Class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function Login($user_email, $user_pass, $remember = false)
    {
        $user_pass = sha1($user_pass);
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $query->bindValue(':email', $user_email);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $user = $query->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if($user->password == $user_pass) {
                $_SESSION['loggd_id'] = $user->id;
                if($remember == true) {
                    setcookie('lggd_sess', hash('sha512', uniqid()), 84600);
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return 'Incorrect Email/Password Combination.';
            }
        } else {
            return 'Incorrect Email/Password.';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `->rowCount()` on SELECT statements don't work reliably across PDO backends. You can just use `->fetch()` and check whether the result is `false` or not.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using SHA-512 right now but I think I'll change it to mcrypt later.

Neither of those are the proper tool for the job. Mcrypt is meant for symmetric encryption (AES, TwoFish, DES, etc.), not password hashing.

If you're running PHP 5.5+, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Otherwise, https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat is the way to go.

EDIT: Example code:

```
<?php
Class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

public function Login($user_email, $user_pass, $remember = false)
{
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $query->bindValue(':email', $user_email);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $user = $query->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if (password_verify($user_pass, $user->password)) {
                $_SESSION['loggd_id'] = $user->id;
                if($remember == true) {
                    setcookie('lggd_sess', hash('sha512', mcrypt_create_iv(64, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), 84600);
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return 'Incorrect Email/Password Combination.';
            }
        } else {
            return 'Incorrect Email/Password.';
        }
    }
}
```

When you insert a row in the DB, you want to use `password_hash($user_password)`

Comment: +1 for `password_hash()` / `password_verify()`. It's too bad we can't all be on 5.5 yet though...

Comment: That's what password_compat is for. If you run PHP < 5.5.0, it polyfills it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's go through this line by line, and talk about it:

```
Class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function Login($user_email, $user_pass, $remember = false)
    {
        $user_pass = sha1($user_pass);
```

OK, let's stop right here. First off, `sha1` is not acceptable for any cryptographic usage.

Second, neither is any other "normal" hash function. You need to salt and stretch the password hash so that it's difficult to brute force. You really should be using bcrypt to hash the passwords.

[How do you use BCrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php/17073604#17073604).

In modern versions of PHP, use `password_hash` (built in with 5.5+, and I maintain a [compatibility library for 5.3.7+](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). In that case, the line would be removed, since the test would happen later.

```
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $query->bindValue(':email', $user_email);
        $query->execute();
```

You're using prepared statements! **EXCELLENT**.

```
        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $user = $query->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if($user->password == $user_pass) {
```

With `password_hash`, this line would become `if (password_verify($user_pass, $user->password)) {`. Simple, easy and secure.

```
                $_SESSION['loggd_id'] = $user->id;
                if($remember == true) {
                    setcookie('lggd_sess', hash('sha512', uniqid()), 84600);
```

`uniqid` should [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593807/md5uniqid-makes-sense-for-random-unique-tokens) be [used](http://securitymaverick.com/php-uniqid-entropy-analysis-and-potentially-vulnerable-apps/) for [security](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html). It's predictable, and gives very little protection against brute forcing.

Instead, you want to use a random token that's generated from `/dev/urandom` or a similar strong source. I maintain 2 libraries that abstract this process [RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib) and [RandomCompat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/random_compat).

Using RandomLib, the hash would be replaced with `$factory = new RandomLib\Factory; $generator = $factory->getMediumStrengthGenerator(); $token = $generator->generateString(32);`. Which would generate a 32 character token using a-zA-Z0-9.

Additionally, how is the remember me token supposed to work if you're not actually storing the value of the token anywhere except in the cookie...???

```
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return 'Incorrect Email/Password Combination.';
            }
        } else {
            return 'Incorrect Email/Password.';
```

There's no practical need to distinguish between an email that you couldn't find, and a password being incorrect. The security it adds is 0 (since you'll likely have registration checks that will leak the existence of an email anyway). So for usability purposes, I'd recommend specifying which field was incorrect...

```
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[You should read up on using salts](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.salt), your approach is too simplistic.

Your use of returns seems too complex though, can I counter-propose something like

```
public function Login($user_email, $user_pass, $remember = false)
{
    $user_pass = sha1($user_pass);
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $query->bindValue(':email', $user_email);
    $query->execute();

    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        $user = $query->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if($user->password == $user_pass) {
            $_SESSION['loggd_id'] = $user->id;
            if($remember == true) {
                setcookie('lggd_sess', hash('sha512', uniqid()), 84600);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return 'Incorrect Email/Password Combination.';
}
```

Comment: Yea....this one is better

Comment: @DJDavid98 adding that feature allows for username harvesting, and is frowned upon in general (OWASP etc.)

Comment: @konijn that's true, and I would follow that advice. But usernames can generally also be harvested from the registration page (there, they have to tell you that the username already exists).

Comment: @tim Hilarious, I never considered that.

Answer (score 2):

- It appears you're storing the password in your database without salting your hash. Adding a user-by-user salt will improve the security of your code.
- This code block has a bunch of extra stuff:

  ```
  if($remember == true) {
      setcookie('lggd_sess', hash('sha512', uniqid()), 84600);
      return true;
  }
  return true;
  ```

  In particular, the `return` statement is duplicated. You can just do this instead:

  ```
  if ($remember) {
      setcookie('lggd_sess', hash('sha512', uniqid()), 84600);
  }
  return true;
  ```
- Just gonna point out that the manual page for `uniqid()` explicitly states:

  > **Warning** This function does not create random nor unpredictable strings. This function must not be used for security purposes. Use a cryptographically secure random function/generator and cryptographically secure hash functions to create unpredictable secure IDs.

Comment: Have a question, does that matter to use a strong hash in CSRF protections or in remember me cookies? Because why would a attacker dcrypt it?

Comment: The hash function is meaningless. The important thing is random entropy to remove the ability for an attacker to guess a valid session id (or remember me token). If they can guess one, it's game over (session hijacking, etc). So the problem isn't `hash`, but `uniqid`...

Answer (score -3):

Only thing I could think of adding right now would be,

```
if (isset($user_pass)) {
    $user_pass = htmlspecialchars($user_pass);
    $user_pass = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $user_pass);
}
if (isset($user_email)) {
    $user_email = htmlspecialchars($user_email );
    $user_email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $user_email);
}
```

Even though you prepare your statement and bind your variable, it doesn't hurt to escape any characters that may break your query.

Also, consider removing all unnecessary white space?

Comment: Yup actually those have been added now in my code just have query about session and cookie. I'm bit doubt about it.

Comment: -1. Escape on output (display), not on input.